# Strings of characters implementation

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

In C, how can I declare and use/manipulate a an array of strings?

For example, it could be

```
a[1]="Apples";
a[2]="Pineapples are red"
```

How can I access these elements and modify them?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `a` must be an array of pointers to char, e.g. `char *a[5]`, to which you then assign pointers to string literals:

```
a[1]="Apples";
a[2]="Pineapples are red";
```

You can modify an element in the sense to let it point to a different string, e.g. `a[1]="another fruit";`. You can access an entire string like, for example, `printf("%s", a[1])`, and you can access single characters like, for example, `char willBeA_p = a[1][1]`; But you cannot modify the contents of the strings in your example, because they are string literals (and modifying string literals yields undefined behaviour). So `a[1][1]='b'` is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can define an array of strings like:
    `char * array_of_strings[100];`
and use `malloc` to allocate memory for each of them.

```
array_of_strings[0] = (char *) malloc(100);
array_of_strings[0] = "here is your string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration:  data_type array_name[array_size];

Example: float mark[5];

You can access elements of an array by indices. Suppose you declared an array mark as above. The first element is mark[0], second element is mark[1] and so on.

It's possible to initialize an array during declaration. For example.

int mark[5] = {19, 10, 8, 17, 9};